# Measure time for function-runtime in tests with compiler optimization in c++

Tags: c++, performance

I want to measure the time a function I programmed takes when executed. While there are many threads on SO on how to measure time in c++, I did not find any that explains how to prevent the compiler optimization to clear away my function-call.
So right now I do something like:

```
bool testFunctionSpeed() {
    auto input = loadInput();
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i; i < num_iterations; i++) {
    auto result = function(input);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
}
```

It appears to work right now, but I'm not sure if this is stable, because:
Doing this, the compiler can see that the result stored in "result" is not used outside of the loop's scope, so it might just optimize the code away (...right?).

I am aware that there are flags to not optimize the code, however I want to benchmark my code under "real" conditions! One way would be to randomly printf out parts of the result, however that does not seem to be a "correct" solution.

What is the right approach to this?

Comment: just use google benchmark it has function `DoNotOptimize` [here is online tool](https://quick-bench.com/) to try it.

Comment: I assume that you will want to see the duration values some day ? If the compiler sees an output statement, it will abstain from optimizing the calls away. [I did not say that you must output immediately, nor that you have to output the individual values. Anything that has a dependency on the measurements is good enough.] So in practice, there is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: Maybe try to store each result value in a `std::array` or a `std::vector` (obviously it should be big enough to contain all of them). Then the compiler won't optimize your for loop away. Using the `std::cout` will just slow down your loop and it won't be an accurate timing.

Comment: If you are still not reassured, you can store the timing measurement in a *volatile* variable.

Comment: The trick I am sometimes using is `return result[0]`. Not sure it is something you would call *correct*. For me, using `printf` is fine too.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the comment. While I'm not using the result stored in "result" at any point, I will printf the duration. Are you sure there is nothing one needs to do? How can the compiler know that he has to actually calculate whats in "result", when I do not specifically tell him?

Comment: @MarekR I thought of that but isnt that changing the result of the measurement? I have no problems with the compiler optimizing whats happening "inside" the function, I just want the result to be calculated in any case.

Comment: So what I'm doing now is to calculate a random integer during runtime and if that is 42 (which is highly unlikely), it will print out the whole content of the variable "result". But that again does not seem to be the correct way of doing it

Comment: @Dennis `DoNotOptimize` does nothing. It just confuses compiler so it will not optimize away a value when optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @Dennis: the compiler is smart enough to see when some data is in fact not used and this is how it discards "dead code". Sorry, I confused the call of the tested function and that of the timing functions. So yes, you need to somehow use "result". An option is to make it volatile. Another could be to accumulate it to a temporary that you print in the end.

Comment: https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk?t=2441

Comment: My question: Why we should measure something which can be optimized away? If you talk about "real world" application execution measurement, we talk about fully optimized code. And if we have a visible function, it might be "executed" in compile time, maybe inlined, maybe reduced to only a few things need to be done in calling context. As this the general idea to measure it in worst case szenario without optimization did not help at all. But to get worst results, you simply should have func in a different translation unit. As the compiler has no idea of side effects, it must be executed.

Comment: @Klaus The output of the function would be (of course) used in the real application. Its just that I want to measure the delay of the function itself in a controlled environment to make decisions on certain aspects of the code

Comment: You misunderstand me! If the compiler sees the definition of the function and the context of the caller, there is a good chance that the code will be optimized a lot. Measuring in a different context can result in total different results. If compiler inlines the code everything is different to a function which is not visible and must be really called. That is why splitting methods out in cpp files often results in very bad generated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent compiler from optimizing away function calls just make input and output of that function a `volatile` variable.

Result is guaranteed to be computed and stored in volatile **output** variable on each loop run.

While volatile **input** will prevent optimizer from precomputing value of your function in advance, if you don't mark input as volatile then compiler may just write a constant to output result variable on each loop iteration.

Click `Try it online!` linke below to see program in action and also assembly listing.

Your code example with improvements is below:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/KdqMMKW11)

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int function(int x) {
    return int(std::log2(x));
}

bool testFunctionSpeed() {
    size_t const num_iterations = 1 << 20;
    auto volatile input = 123;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
        auto volatile result = function(input);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
        end - start).count() / num_iterations;
    std::cout << duration << " ns per iteration" << std::endl;
    return true;
}


int main() {
    testFunctionSpeed();
}
```

Output:

```
8 ns per iteration
```

Comment: adding "volatile" to my code restrictes the c++ in my function. At least I'm getting error messages that i did not get otherwise

Comment: @Dennis You can make a wrapper for your function that accepts volatile, this wrapper should forward call to your function, don't modify your original function at all. Then just measure running time of your wrapper. Please send me precise signature of your function and I'll make a wrapper for it and update my answer with improved code.

Comment: @Dennis I think you didn't understand code in my answer. You don't need to modify signature of your function, no need to make its arguments or return type `volatile`, you just make variables `input` and `result` volatile, see my code. These two variables are only used in time measurement code, nowhere else. To repeat - you don't need to modify your original function at all.

Comment: WOW, I completely forgot about `volatile` qualifier and never used it. But it is essential in profiling. I used just `/Od` before to force compiler not to collapse and skip test loops, but this approach has much problems. If you compare your `inline` function to some outside library's function, `/Od` code will call optimised lib's function, while your function will be inlined into the *unoptimised* code, which will make it seem like your function is *much* slower. By making wrappers and using `volatile` you can ensure that the test will be accurate!

Comment: I also want to suggest you wrap your test loop (i.e. `testFunctionSpeed()` in your example) in the `#pragma optimize( "", off )` and `#pragma optimize( "", on )` block. This will ensure that no loops or timing logic will ever be screwed by optimisation. You can then add additional wrapper for your test code and `__declspec(noinline)` it, so that it will always be called from your unoptimised loop. After that use `volatile` inside the wrapper for your variables, and voila, accurate test! This, of course, will only work in MSVC, but you might be able to do similar in other compilers.